# PHPStorm change color for diff gutter and collapse arrows in editor

Tags: php, colors, ide, phpstorm

I recently switched to a dark theme ( Earthsong ) and have noticed in the editor that I can not see the expand/collapse arrows and the clickable "diff" link that goes to the **left** of the line numbers in the editor (not the line showing a line change to the right of the editor screen). Any one know how to change the color of the two? Searched online and nothing.

Comment: you can probaby try changing gutter background in Settings/Editor/Colors&Fonts/General...

Comment: great theme, I reccomend #463E38 for the tear line

Answer (score 13):

I actually found the answer. To change the collapse arrow color and the clickable "diff" link that goes to the left of the line numbers in the editor it is the Tear line value under
Settings/Editor/Colors&Fonts/General.

Answer (score 5):

The background color seems to be uneditable.
But the outline and symbol seems to be available, the background of the arrows are inherited from the background of your code background from what i can tell.

`File -> Settings -> Editor ->Colors & Fonts -> General :: Tear line`

( Notice the **Background** option is dulled/disabled )